# I'm getting unresolved reference when using trying to add a badge to BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, material-design, badge

For some reason anything related to Material Badge is showing up as unresolved for me.

I'm including material in my project:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

I'm just trying to add any badge to a menu item:

```
val menuItemId = R.id.navigation_item1
val navView: BottomNavigationView = this.findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
navView.getOrCreateBadge(menuItemId)
```

But I get

> Unresolved reference: getOrCreateBadge

I feel like it should be something simple, but I'm not having any luck. Anyone else seen this before? Thanks.

Comment: Did you migrate your code to `AndroidX` correctly?

Comment: Yeah I believe so. I'm also seeing this on a new project that started off using AndroidX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the version to 1.1.0-beta02 and now it works as expected. I don't know why `badge` wasn't available in the 1.0.0 package. From what I could tell it should have been.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta02'
```

Answer (score 0):

`getOrCreateBadge` functionality of `BottomNavigationView` has been introduced in 
`v1.1.0-alpha08`. So, you have to use at least `v1.1.0-alpha08` to get these functionality.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08'
```

But always it's recommended to use latest version. Latest version is `1.2.0-alpha02`

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'
```

Check latest version [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.material/material).

Comment: I would rather use a beta version than an alpha release.